# QScrollArea with FlowLayout widgets not resizing properly

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a widget similar to the KDE (or Gnome or MacOS) system settings (e.g., like this picture)

[image]

I already implemented a FlowLayout from the [Qt docs exampe](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html).

If I put some FlowLayout widgets (wrapped in a container widget with a QVBoxLayout) into a QScrollArea and resize the QSrollArea, everything flows and re-layouts as it shoulds.

*However*, if I increase the scroll area’s width so that it needs less height, the scroll area’s still thinks that its widgets require
the orginal height for their minimumWidth:

[image: 0_1507630989642_flow_layout_in_scrollarea.gif]

How can I can I update the scroll area with the actual height of its child so that the vertical scroll bar disappears when it’s no longer needed?

Below, you’ll find the (Python) implementation of the FlowLayout and in the `__main__` block the actual example.

Cheers, 
Stefan

```
"""
PyQt5 port of the `layouts/flowlayout
<https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html>`_ example
from Qt5.

Usage:

    python3 -m pip install pyqt5
    python3 flow_layout.py

"""
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QRect, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLayout, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem


class FlowLayout(QLayout):
    """A ``QLayout`` that aranges its child widgets horizontally and
    vertically.

    If enough horizontal space is available, it looks like an ``HBoxLayout``,
    but if enough space is lacking, it automatically wraps its children into
    multiple rows.

    """
    heightChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, margin=0, spacing=-1):
        super().__init__(parent)
        if parent is not None:
            self.setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)
        self.setSpacing(spacing)

        self._item_list = []

    def __del__(self):
        while self.count():
            self.takeAt(0)

    def addItem(self, item):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self._item_list.append(item)

    def addSpacing(self, size):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self.addItem(QSpacerItem(size, 0, QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

    def count(self):
        return len(self._item_list)

    def itemAt(self, index):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list[index]
        return None

    def takeAt(self, index):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list.pop(index)
        return None

    def expandingDirections(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name,no-self-use
        return Qt.Orientations(Qt.Orientation(0))

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name,no-self-use
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        height = self._do_layout(QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)
        return height

    def setGeometry(self, rect):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        super().setGeometry(rect)
        self._do_layout(rect, False)

    def sizeHint(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        return self.minimumSize()

    def minimumSize(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        size = QSize()

        for item in self._item_list:
            minsize = item.minimumSize()
            extent = item.geometry().bottomRight()
            size = size.expandedTo(QSize(minsize.width(), extent.y()))

        margin = self.contentsMargins().left()
        size += QSize(2 * margin, 2 * margin)
        return size

    def _do_layout(self, rect, test_only=False):
        m = self.contentsMargins()
        effective_rect = rect.adjusted(+m.left(), +m.top(), -m.right(), -m.bottom())
        x = effective_rect.x()
        y = effective_rect.y()
        line_height = 0

        for item in self._item_list:
            wid = item.widget()

            space_x = self.spacing()
            space_y = self.spacing()
            if wid is not None:
                space_x += wid.style().layoutSpacing(
                    QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Horizontal)
                space_y += wid.style().layoutSpacing(
                    QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Vertical)

            next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
            if next_x - space_x > effective_rect.right() and line_height > 0:
                x = effective_rect.x()
                y = y + line_height + space_y
                next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
                line_height = 0

            if not test_only:
                item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

            x = next_x
            line_height = max(line_height, item.sizeHint().height())

        new_height = y + line_height - rect.y()
        self.heightChanged.emit(new_height)
        return new_height


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


    class Container(QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
            self._widgets = []

        def sizeHint(self):
            w = self.size().width()
            h = 0
            for widget in self._widgets:
                h += widget.layout().heightForWidth(w)

            sh = super().sizeHint()
            print(sh)
            print(w, h)
            return sh

        def add_widget(self, widget):
            self._widgets.append(widget)
            self.layout().addWidget(widget)

        def add_stretch(self):
            self.layout().addStretch()


    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    container = Container()
    for i in range(2):
        w = QWidget()
        w.setWindowTitle('Flow Layout')
        l = FlowLayout(w, 10)
        w.setLayout(l)
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('Short'))
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('Longer'))
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('Different text'))
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('More text'))
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('Even longer button text'))
        container.add_widget(w)
    container.add_stretch()

    sa = QScrollArea()
    sa.setWidgetResizable(True)
    sa.setWidget(container)
    sa.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The [icon view](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#viewMode-prop) of `QListView` already has this functionality. The kde settings program looks like it uses multiple list-views in a scroll-area.

Comment: Thanks alot for the hint. I toyed around with it and it works in theory but imho looks less nice than the flow layout. Furthermore, if I add multiple (Icon)ListViews to a SrollArea, each list view has its own scrollbar and the parent scrollarea has no scrollbar.

Comment: You should be able to change the scroll-bar policy on the list-views. I also don't see any reason why the scroll-area can't be configured to produce a scroll-bar. You can also remove the frames on the list-views to get a fairly seamless looking combined widget.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was (surprisingly) simple: Use the FlowLayout’s `heightChanged` signal to update the minimum height of the container (the ScrollArea’s widget).

Here is a working example:

```
"""
PyQt5 port of the `layouts/flowlayout
<https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html>`_ example
from Qt5.

"""
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QPoint, QRect, QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLayout, QSizePolicy, QSpacerItem


class FlowLayout(QLayout):
    """A ``QLayout`` that aranges its child widgets horizontally and
    vertically.

    If enough horizontal space is available, it looks like an ``HBoxLayout``,
    but if enough space is lacking, it automatically wraps its children into
    multiple rows.

    """
    heightChanged = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, margin=0, spacing=-1):
        super().__init__(parent)
        if parent is not None:
            self.setContentsMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin)
        self.setSpacing(spacing)

        self._item_list = []

    def __del__(self):
        while self.count():
            self.takeAt(0)

    def addItem(self, item):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self._item_list.append(item)

    def addSpacing(self, size):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self.addItem(QSpacerItem(size, 0, QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Minimum))

    def count(self):
        return len(self._item_list)

    def itemAt(self, index):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list[index]
        return None

    def takeAt(self, index):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        if 0 <= index < len(self._item_list):
            return self._item_list.pop(index)
        return None

    def expandingDirections(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name,no-self-use
        return Qt.Orientations(Qt.Orientation(0))

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name,no-self-use
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        height = self._do_layout(QRect(0, 0, width, 0), True)
        return height

    def setGeometry(self, rect):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        super().setGeometry(rect)
        self._do_layout(rect, False)

    def sizeHint(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        return self.minimumSize()

    def minimumSize(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        size = QSize()

        for item in self._item_list:
            minsize = item.minimumSize()
            extent = item.geometry().bottomRight()
            size = size.expandedTo(QSize(minsize.width(), extent.y()))

        margin = self.contentsMargins().left()
        size += QSize(2 * margin, 2 * margin)
        return size

    def _do_layout(self, rect, test_only=False):
        m = self.contentsMargins()
        effective_rect = rect.adjusted(+m.left(), +m.top(), -m.right(), -m.bottom())
        x = effective_rect.x()
        y = effective_rect.y()
        line_height = 0

        for item in self._item_list:
            wid = item.widget()

            space_x = self.spacing()
            space_y = self.spacing()
            if wid is not None:
                space_x += wid.style().layoutSpacing(
                    QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Horizontal)
                space_y += wid.style().layoutSpacing(
                    QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Vertical)

            next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
            if next_x - space_x > effective_rect.right() and line_height > 0:
                x = effective_rect.x()
                y = y + line_height + space_y
                next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
                line_height = 0

            if not test_only:
                item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

            x = next_x
            line_height = max(line_height, item.sizeHint().height())

        new_height = y + line_height - rect.y()
        self.heightChanged.emit(new_height)
        return new_height


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QGroupBox

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    container = QWidget()
    container_layout = QVBoxLayout()
    for i in range(2):
        g = QGroupBox(f'Group {i}')
        l = FlowLayout(margin=10)
        l.heightChanged.connect(container.setMinimumHeight)
        g.setLayout(l)
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('Short'))
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('Longer'))
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('Different text'))
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('More text'))
        l.addWidget(QPushButton('Even longer button text'))
        container_layout.addWidget(g)
    container_layout.addStretch()
    container.setLayout(container_layout)

    w = QScrollArea()
    w.setWindowTitle('Flow Layout')
    w.setWidgetResizable(True)
    w.setWidget(container)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```